# Proftpd port-forwarding failing

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, port-forwarding, ftp, passive

I'm setting up proftpd on an ec2 Instance running Ubuntu 10.04

I've gone through all the forums and tried every suggestion but still can't seem to get it working.  I know the problem is with the passive ports but everything I've tried has failed.

The filezilla log shows:

```
Status: Resolving address of ec2-50-110-20-81.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Status: Connecting to 50.110.20.81:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 ProFTPD 1.3.2c Server (Michaels Main) [50.110.20.81]
Command:    USER cube
Response:   331 Password required for cube
Command:    PASS *******
Response:   230 User cube logged in
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 UTF8 set to on
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/home/cube" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Error:  Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

In my proftpd.conf file I have the following lines for setting up the passive ports:

```
ServerType                      inetd
PassivePorts                    60000 60200
MasqueradeAddress               51.110.20.81
```

My iptables -L -v looks like this:

```
4475 370K ACCEPT all -- any any anywhere anywhere state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   0    0 ACCEPT tcp -- any any anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:ftp-data
  13  676 ACCEPT tcp -- any any anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:ftp
   1   40 ACCEPT tcp -- any any anywhere anywhere tcp dpts:60000:60200
   0    0 ACCEPT tcp -- any any anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:ssh
```

netstat --vatn:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.252.45.220:22        214.11.175.64:18169     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward is set to 1.

I've uncommented the net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 line in /etc/sysctl.conf

This has my head fried, any ideas?  If I've left anything out please let me know.

Thanks for your help, cheers!

Comment: This is EC2, so did you set up the Security Group for this instance to allow the passive port traffic?

Comment: Ports 60000 - 60200 are open in my Security Group

Answer (score 2):

Did you open ports 60000 to 60200 in your EC2 security group ?

Comment: Ports 60000 to 60200 are open in my ec2 security group.  Thanks for the suggestion though.